# SQL query to find subscribers who were sent with the same Email Name

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, query, dataextensions, sql

I've been using marketing cloud for almost a year now but not really exploring the SQL queries since i'm not really familiar with this. I'm also aware that my friend set up my account with lots of user initiated emails.

Now I'm in the dilemma on how can I find subscribers that were sent with a specific email name at a time range. Example i have 15 JobId with the same Email name and i wanted to collate all subscribers from these JobIDs with  in one data extension.

On this DE, I will be needing the following columns:

SubscriberKey
JobID
BatchID
SendDate
OpenDate
ClickDate

Comment: Can you update your question with a query that you wrote as a starting point? If you provide a query we can advise on how to fix but we try to avoid doing the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

Bookmark this - it will become your best friend
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_views.htm&type=5

Marketing Cloud uses Data Views to store information about events that have to do with email. These views are kept for a soft 90-ish days before the tracking is archived on their side (depends on how much you send and to how many users = amount of data they have to keep available etc)

You can access these data views in a query by referencing them as a table like as follows:
_Jobs,
_Sent,
_Open,
etc.

From this it sounds like you are looking for a particular email name and user it was sent to - you can do this by inner joining the _Job, _sent, _click, _open, and _subscribers data views:

> Select DISTINCT
>   t1.JobID,
>   t1.EmailName,
>   t2.SubscriberKey,
>   t3.EmailAddress,
>   t2.EventDate as 'SentDt',
>   t4.EventDate as 'OpenDt',
>   t5.EventDate as 'ClickDt'
>   FROM
>   _Job t1
>   INNER JOIN
>   _Sent t2
>   ON
>   t1.JobID = t2.JobID
>   INNER JOIN
>   _Subscribers t3
>   t2.SubscriberID = t3.SubscriberID
>   Left Join
>   _Open t4
>   ON
>   t2.SubscriberID = t4.SubscriberID AND t2.ListID = t4.ListID AND t2.BatchID = t4.BatchID AND t2.JobID = t4.JobID
>   LEFT JOIN
>   _Click t5
>   ON
>   t2.SubscriberID = t5.SubscriberID AND t2.ListID = t5.ListID AND t2.BatchID = t5.BatchID AND t2.JobID = t5.JobID
>   WHERE t1.EmailName = 'Your Exact Email Creative Name' AND
>   t2.EventDate BETWEEN '10/01/2019' AND '10/02/2019'

Write it to a data extension with JobID NUMBER, EmailName Text(250),  SubscriberKey Text(250),EmailAddress as Text(250), SentDt DATE, OpenDt DATE Nullable, ClickDt Date Nullable.

This query should give you a list of the contacts that were sent a certain email within a certain time frame.

Keep in mind - you might get duplicates if the contact was sent the email more than once, opened more than once, or clicked more than once. If you want specifics or don't care as long as they were sent and either opened or clicked, you should:

- add a MAX() around your EventDates and add a Group By t1.JobID,
  t1.EmailName,
  t2.SubscriberKey,
  t3.EmailAddress
- Remove JobID from the Select query all together and remove from your destination data extension.

Be careful to read notes about the enterprise-level accounts and the timestamps being in different time zones.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @Bread2287 Appreciated your reply and yes, i'm just looking for for a particular email name and user it was sent to. This is promising and got excited about this. One speedbump though. I kept getting an "Error updating filter" whenever i write the data extension.

Comment: Are you creating the data extension from scratch? Or using an existing one? Make sure it is not a filtered data extension (in both the source DE and the destination DE -- it could cause problems)? It needs to be a standard data extension. You can also try to just create a brand new destination data extension to test the query that everything is writing as expected.

Comment: Hello @Bread2287 yes im doing the DE from scratch. Ill test it again now and see how it goes.

Comment: Hello @Bread2287 i'm still encountering error when creating the DE. i'll post something that i was able to made it work.

Comment: Hello @Bread2287 i figured it out. the i checked sendable in making the DE that's why I encountered the error. I was able to make the DE but after writing the query, I got no results at all

Answer (score 0):

I tried this query to look for subscriber's opendate senddate, and clickdate by JobId and it works like charm.

Select distinct
s.SubscriberKey,
s.JobID,
s.BatchID,
convert(char(19),o.EventDate,20) as OpenDate,
convert(char(19),c.EventDate,20) as ClickDate,
convert(char(19),s.EventDate,20) as SendDate
from [_sent] s
left join [_open] o
on s.JobID = o.JobID and s.ListID = o.ListID and s.BatchID = o.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = o.SubscriberID and o.IsUnique = 1
left join [_click] c
on s.JobID = c.JobID and s.ListID = c.ListID and s.BatchID = c.BatchID and s.SubscriberID = c.SubscriberID and c.IsUnique = 1
where
s.JobID = 154670

[image: Here's the target data extension]

i'm asking for your help guys to tweaked this to pull these info in the name fields plus  email address and job ID in reference to EmailName.

Comment: @Bread2287 Hope you can help me out on this cuz i think we are on the right track with your answer earlier.